# Script to send new files via email from monitored folder

Tags: email, powershell, vbscript, attachment

I'm wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of how to automate the sending of newly added files located in a monitored folder via email (Exchange), ideally without Outlook installed on the server.

I use scripts daily to notify me of changes in a watched folder via email, but none of these actually attach the files on the email, and at best only list the new files names etc.

We have software that outputs 3 small text files at roughly the same time day, but someone then has to email those manually to the same external address each day. I'd like to automate that process.

I'm running Server 2008 R2, and don't mind PowerShell and VB etc. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going.

```
$watchPath = "c:\folder\"

$sendToList = @("toUser@domain.com")
$sendFrom = "fromUser@domain.com"
$emailSubject = "File '{0}' changed"
$smtpHost = "smtp.server"

$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher 
$watcher.Path = $watchPath
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action { 

    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpHost -To $sendToList -from $sendFrom -Subject ($emailSubject -f $eventArgs.Name) -Attachments $eventArgs.FullPath

}
```